# Error deploying SQL Server 2008 r2 Reporting Services data extension

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to write my own data extension for SSRS 2008 r2. I have created a very basic extension that should just return a simple dataset based on [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152917.aspx). I followed the deployment instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155104.aspx) and used [this sample](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS20082!Active%20Directory%20Extension%20Sample&referringTitle=Home) for reference.

In BI Dev Studio I can create a Data Source using my new Type (AS) and create a dataset using the source. When I type a query and click OK, I get this error message:

> The selected data extension AS is not installed or cannot be loaded. 
>   Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for
>   local reports and on the report server for published reports.

I've checked over my config files many times and tried adding the 'CodeGroup' before, after and within the existing CodeGroups since the instructions aren't very clear without success.

I have signed my assembly and put the dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin`. I've also done lots of googling.

I'm not sure what other information would be useful. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are compiling your data extension to target .NET 3.5. This resolved some similar problems I encountered a few months ago.

Comment: So simple, yet so frustrating. It crossed my mind at some point too... thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem with my extended data source. But this doesn't  resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If You using assembly You will also must write CodeGroup into this file (my instance for Express Edition):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportServer
```

**Did You try this?**

Comment: Yes, I added the CodeGroup xml to both rssrvpolicy.config (in the directory you provided) and RSPreviewPolicy.config.

Comment: Hmm. Mesage say You don't have installed AS extension on local for report server. Did You do that? Also did You try restart Server?

Comment: As far as I can tell I've done everything necessary to install the extension for both the report designer and server. Yep, I restart the service each time I try something and have since rebooted.

Comment: You are connect to local database or external?

Comment: Everything is installed on a single PC. My data extension doesn't actually connect to a database at the moment; it should just return a hard-coded test dataset.

Comment: Did you add entries in the policy file for dependent assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

You also have to install the plugin for your visual studio

From my last installation documentation:

```
Installing on the Developer PC ( for creating Reports with the plugin )
```

Copy the assemblies to the following folder (  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Report Designer)
Make the same change to rspreviewpolicy.config as you did for rssvrpolicy.config on the server.

My changes for the policy file

Add to rssrvPoliciy.config ( Same folder as rsreportserver.config)
For each dll a security entry must be added!

Insert the block inside following CodeGroup Node
...

```
<CodeGroup class="FirstMatchCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="Execution" Description="This code group grants MyComputer code Execution permission. ">
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name="ADONETDataset" Description="ADONETDataset DPE"> <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Reporting Instance Name\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ADF.Reporting.SRS.DPE.ADODataset.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="FullTrust" Name="ADF_System" Description="ADF System">
<IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Reporting Instance Name\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ADF.System.dll" />
</CodeGroup>
</CodeGroup>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me while examining the assembly references of the DLL.
You need to reference at lease one object from the assembly Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions!

In my class, I just declared an unused variable, and it worked:
public Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.Utf8StringWriter ww;